# Detecting if a supply is 50Hz AC or DC

Tags: ac, dc, indicator

I have a power supply which I can select either 12V/24V DC or 12V/24V (50Hz) AC. This would be selected at the run time of the supply. I want to add an indicator to the supply output which indicates if it supplies AC or DC. An LED should be powered on if supply is DC but should be powered off if it's AC. Theoretically this could be done with an inductor in series but I have abandoned that idea since calculated inductance values were huge. Instead I came up with following,

[image]

I have tested this on a breadboard and it works perfectly. However I feel this is bit of an overkill. I couldn't come up with any simpler solution. Any suggestions for a simpler solution I can get the same results? ( Please note the series/parallel resistor/capacitors are used only because I didn't have exact equivalent values )

Comment: The LED is a classic colored one which consumes around 30mA @ 2.4V

Comment: @ThePhoton I would like to remove the transistor if possible.

Comment: The transistor and LED work only when powered from a proper positive DC voltage. A 12V or 24V AC supply voltage will slowly destroy the transistor and LED since the AC voltages exceed the maximum allowed negative voltage for the transistor and LED as listed on their datasheets. The very high values for the resistors will cause low currents resulting in a very dim LED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might get something like this to work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNcJJk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'll leave finding the appropriate values as an exercise for you. R1 should be chosen to give the desired LED brightness when a DC source is supplied. C1 must be big enough to effectively short the LED when an AC source is supplied.

One thing to watch out for is to make sure the LED is able to withstand the negative voltage that will be applied to it during the negative half-cycle in case of an AC input. If you can't find an LED that's capable of that, you might have to connect a second diode anti-parallel to the LED.

Comment: Ah yes! This seems reasonable enough. I'll do the math and test it out, thanks :)

Comment: R1 = 10k, C1 = 10uF worked well for my LED

Answer (score 4):

You may use a 2-pin bicolor LED and a resistor. For example https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/94553.pdf

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcBjbq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you have AC, both internal LEDs will light up, (each a different color), and if you have DC only one LED will light up.

Comment: if you may encounter colourblind users using two LEDs is a better way to do it.

Comment: Indeed this is a cool solution, but I need 2 distinct LEDs to indicate AC/DC rather than 1 color changing LED.